# Efficient way to extract a substring from string based on specific criteria?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I have got a list of strings, taken from the selectorText of many CSSRule, the strings has the general form (not sure about that RegEx):

```
".selector1 .elementClass[, ]*"
```

Concrete Examples are the following:

```
".point"
".point.lackofclearance .stand_b, .point.lackofclearance .stand_c"
".point .path_a,.point .path,.point .stand"
".blink_on .point.direction_open .stand"
".blink_off .point.a_in_ratc_selection .path_a, .blink_off .point
 .path.a_in_ratc_selection"
```

Now, out of such strings, interesting are those containing the string "`point`", and out of those string that contain the string "`point`", I am interested in the substring coming immediately after "`.point.`" and before the next space character. They represent states of Elements that I would like to read.

For example:

From "`.point`" there is no such substring to extract, and from "`.point .path_a,.point .path,.point .stand`" also, nothing to extract, because "`.point.`" doesn't exist as one piece at all. **BUT** for  "`.point.lackofclearance .stand_b, .point.lackofclearance .stand_c`" I would like to extract "`lackofclearance`" , the first and second occurence of it, of course.

I have an idea in my head already, and that is:

- Check if the string "`point`" exists
- If yes, split the string by '`,`'
- for each resulting substring, split by '' (space character)
- for each resulting substring, containing "`.point`.", split by '`.`' (dot char)
- take the second substring of the last split

Does any body has another suggestion, a chic way of doing it, may be shorter, or more efficient, or both...
It has to be done in JavaScript, in Chrome, jQuery is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are awesome.  You simply look for a literal `".point."` followed by a word `"\w+"`.  Capture that word with parens `(\w+)`.  Then call `match` on a string, pass in the regex and get the second item of the returned result, which is the captured subgroup word, the thing you want.

```
var whatWeFound = ".point.omgyesawesome .foo".match(/\.point\.(\w+)/)[1];
console.log(whatWeFound); //=> "omgyesawesome"
```

Comment: Sorry, the RegEx you provided, returned only the first occurance, so if I have ".point.lackofclearance .stand_b, .point.lackofclearanceCritical .stand_c" , I can only extract lackofclearance, but I also want lackofclearanceCritical. I then tried this /\.point\.(\S+)/g RegEx, I get as a result [".point.lackofclearance", ".point.lackofclearanceCritical"] , not exactly what I want, but I can then apply your RegEx of each, and take what I want

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = ".point.lackofclearance .stand_b, .point.lackofclearance .stand_c";
var re = /\.point\.(\w+)/g;
var result = [];
var m;
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  result.push(m[1]);
}
// result == ['lackofclearance', 'lackofclearance']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for such a task.

```
var m = selectorText.match(/\.point.\w+/)
for (var i=0; m!=null && i<m.length; i++)
    console.log(m[i].substring(7)); // remove ".point." part
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var strings =  "YOUR_CLASS_STRINGS".split(" ");
var regex = /\.point\.(\S+)/;
var arr = [];

for(x in strings){
    if(regex_string = strings[x].match(regex)){ 
        arr.push(regex_string[1]);
    }
}
```

This should result in `arr` being populated only with the class names the proceed `.point`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers given above, I adjusted the RegEx to fit my needs, and this one seems to do the job.

```
/\.point\.(.+\s)/
```

When Applied

```
".point.vacancy_unknown.direction_open .path_a".match(/\.point\.(.+\s)/)
```

I get the following result.

```
[".point.vacancy_unknown.direction_open ", "vacancy_unknown.direction_open "]
```